# Laravel Use of undefined constant errors - assumed 'errors'

Tags: laravel

Please bear with me I'm new to Laravel.

if I leave the code below out... my form validation seems fine.

```
@if(count(errors) > 0)
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <ul>
      @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
        <li>{{$error}}</li>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
@endif
```

But as soon as I add the above code it Fails and gives me the error :

Use of undefined constant errors - assumed 'errors'

I have the route under this middleware

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){ 
 Route::post('/signup', [
 'uses' => 'UserController@postSignUp',
 'as' => 'signup'
 ]);
}
```

because I have it under that middleware its supposed to have the error constant.

I cant find anything regarding this problem with the display errors.
please can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$errors != errors
```

One is a variable, one is a constant, note the missing `$`.

The error bag would not be a constant since constant values never change, be sure to better familiarize yourself with php types and syntax before even attempting to use Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

`$errors` is a variable whilst `errors` is just a normal word without any reference or meaning to the code editor or programme.

```
@if(count(errors) > 0)
```

In this line, write instead `@if(count($errors) > 0)`, just as same as this line:

```
@foreach($errors->all() as $error)
```

Afterwards, the error will go away and the code will work just fine.

Comment: This doesn't seem to offer much on top of the existing answer from 2018.